# Connection error in Google IoT end-to-end example

Tags: python, google-api, mqtt

I've recently attempted google's iot end-to-end example (https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/samples/end-to-end-sample) out of pure interest. However, towards the final part of the process where I had to connect devices, I kept running into a run time error.

```
Creating JWT using RS256 from private key file rsa_private.pem
Connection Result: 5: The connection was refused.
Disconnected: 5: The connection was refused.
Connection Result: 5: The connection was refused.
Disconnected: 5: The connection was refused.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cloudiot_pubsub_example_mqtt_device.py", line 259, in <module>
    main()
  File "cloudiot_pubsub_example_mqtt_device.py", line 234, in main
    device.wait_for_connection(5)
  File "cloudiot_pubsub_example_mqtt_device.py", line 100, in 
wait_for_connection
    raise RuntimeError('Could not connect to MQTT bridge.')
RuntimeError: Could not connect to MQTT bridge.
```

Above is the error obtained after inserting the command string that was on the clipboard. Below is a more elaborated process of how i got to the error.

Regarding the device ID, i manually created on the google iot platform in the registry. For the private/public rsa key pair, I generated them following Google's instruction and pasted the public key in the device's public key and copied the private key into the same directory with the python files in them.

Thanks.

Comment: Same issue - any update?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, just pass the correct cloud region parameter to the command --cloud_region=asia-east1

Answer (score -1):

You can try giving cloud region when running device script Ex : "--cloud_region=asia-east1"

python cloudiot_pubsub_example_mqtt_device.py --project_id=applied-grove-246108 --registry_id=my-registry --device_id=my-device --private_key_file=rsa_private.pem --algorithm=RS256 --cloud_region=asia-east1